Как выбрать частицы НЕ и НИ в предложении по грамматическим показателям?
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Выбор частиц НЕ и НИ — одна из самых трудных тем в орфографии, особенно  если  предложения похожи друг на друга по форме.
Можно ли решить эту задачу по грамматическим признакам?

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
В данной теме рассматриваются три вида предложений:

Простые восклицательные предложения с отрицательной частицей НЕ

Придаточные уступительные предложения с усилительной частицей НИ

Придаточные определительные предложения с отрицательной частицей НЕ


п1. ПРОСТЫЕ ВОСКЛИЦАТЕЛЬНЫЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ С ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНОЙ ЧАСТИЦЕЙ НЕ
Простые восклицательные предложения с частицей НЕ имеют РИТОРИЧЕСКОЕ значение, при этом заключённое в них отрицание фактически имеет значение СКРЫТОГО УТВЕРЖДЕНИЯ.
Наш брат охотник куда не заходит! 
Кто только не бывал у Горького! 
Как не любить родной Москвы!
Ну как не порадеть родному человечку! 


ПРИДАТОЧНЫЕ УСТУПИТЕЛЬНЫЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ С УСИЛИТЕЛЬНОЙ ЧАСТИЦЕЙ НИ

Частица НИ входит в состав сложноподчиненных союзов КТО НИ, КАК НИ, ГДЕ НИ с уступительным или обобщающе-усилительным значением.
Частица НИ усиливает утвердительный смысл предложения, ее можно изъять из предложения без изменения смысла.
(1) УСТУПИТЕЛЬНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ СОЮЗА
Уступительное значение союза указывает на условие, вопреки которому осуществляется то, о чём говорится в главном предложении: как я ни старался найти время для поездки, ничего не получалось – усилительная частица НИ в составе союзов КУДА НИ, ЧТО НИ, КАК НИ, КОГДА НИ с уступительным значением.
Не мог он ямба от хорея, как мы ни бились, отличить.
Куда бы нас ни бросила судьбина и счастие куда б ни повело, 
всё те же мы: нам целый мир чужбина, отечество нам Царское 
Село.

(2) ОБОБЩАЮЩЕ-УСИЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ СОЮЗА
Обобщающе-усилительное значение подчинительных союзов с частицей НИ в придаточном предложении определяет ПОЛНОТУ ПРОЯВЛЕНИЯ того, о чём говорится в главном предложении: куда ни взглянешь, всюду вода – союзы КУДА НИ, КАК НИ, имеют обобщающе-усилительное значение.
 Как бы то ни было, имя дочери коменданта 
 произнесено не было.
 Куда ни обращаю взор, кругом синеет мрачный бор и 
 день права свои утратил.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ
Сложность различения двух приведенных вариантов с НЕ и НИ заключается в том, что разные по форме синтаксические конструкции – простое восклицательное предложение с НЕ и сложноподчиненное предложение с НИ – передают УТВЕРДИТЕЛЬНЫЙ смысл сообщения.

ПРИДАТОЧНЫЕ ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЬНЫЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ С ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНОЙ ЧАСТИЦЕЙ НЕ

Особое внимание следует обратить на придаточные определительные и местоименно-определительные предложения с частицей НЕ и местоименными словами КУДА, КОГДА, которые по структуре напоминают придаточные уступительные предложения:
это был край (какой?), куда не ступала нога охотника,
КТО, КУДА – союзные слова, отрицательная частица НЕ относится к глаголу.
 И тот не писатель, кто не прибавил к зрению человека хотя 
 бы немного зоркости.
 Кто не знает печали и гнева, тот не любит отчизны своей.

